# PHP Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, methods, undefined, fatal-error

I'm having a problem with my Mail class. It was working before, but now i'm not sure what happened. here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mail::sendTo() in C:\...\web\modules\register.php on line 30
```

My mail class:

```
class Mail
{
public static $Headers = 'From:akshay@myemail.com';
public $sendtowho;
public $subject;
public $message;
public $template;

public function sendTo($who='')
{
    $this->sendtowho = $who;
}

public function with($subj='',$template)
{
    $this->subject = $subj;
    $this->template = $template;
}

public function addVars($variables)
{
    $TemplateHandler = new Template('mail');
    $this->message = $TemplateHandler->renderContent($this->template, $variables);
}

public function send()
{
    mail($this->sendtowho, $this->subject, $this->message, self::$Headers);
}
}
```

My register.php

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->sendTo(User::getMailFromUsername($username));
$mail->with(' Registration Info','registration');
$mail->addVars(array('name' => User::getNameFromUsername($username), 'regKey' => $regKey));
$mail->send();
```

Line where the error is happening:

`$mail->sendTo(User::getMailFromUsername($username));`

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

EDIT: Made some change to names of method and var to, so you can understand it better. BUT STILL GIVING SAME ERROR!!

Comment: So where is $mail being set as an instance of your Mail class?

Comment: where did you initialized the class?

Comment: Search for `$mail = new Mail;` on your code , if not found. Just add it.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line? `Mail::to()` (static) and `Mail->to()` (instance) are different types of functions.

Comment: It was there the initialization. I just forgot to add it on here. Added now. I require the Mail class in the initcore.php which is where it starts.

Comment: You have a public variable `$mail->to` with the same name as a public method `$mail->to()`. I'd guess that's causing the problem. Try changing the name on one of them.

Comment: @doublesharp yup thats the line, i use -> not ::. but the error says with :: idk?

Comment: @MikeW changed the vars to $sendto, i still get the same error.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Just need to change the name of my class from Mail to MailInterface. Mail class is already taken by something else. I am using XAMPP with PHP 5.5.

Comment: A good idea for future class design is: using namespaces, read up on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: @Akshay2598 To be honest, I'd always go for using something like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). It's easy to use, it can send e-mail through many transports (sendmail, smtp, the mail function) etc, and it's taken the necessary precautions for security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Just need to change the name of my class from Mail to MailInterface. Mail class is already taken by something else. I am using XAMPP with PHP 5.5.